# Set the returned value from php using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I am too confused to think over it right now.... My index.html contains a simple `HTML form`, Using `POST` i am sending values to a `php` file, which finally does some db operations and return some message... As simple as that. The problem is that i am unable to print this message in index.html file.
Somebody help.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the specific issue you are having? Error messages? This needz moar infos

Comment: Without any code, or indication of what you're trying, it is impossible to answer this question. Please include details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the index.html an index.php and move your php code to the top of the index file, then make the form submit to itself. This allows you to do live user feedback using echo or similar - without the need for AJAX :)